# Facebook login php hash_hmac() problem after getiing data

Tags: php, facebook, authentication

I am trying to create a facebook login via php based on this tutorial:
https://youtu.be/AMoozUkI2Fg

Everything is fine, I have downloaded data and saved in the session, but I get an error:

> Warning: hash_hmac () expects parameter 2 to be string, object given
> in classes / fb-php-sdk / vendor / facebook / graph-sdk / src /
> Facebook / Authentication / AccessToken.php on line 70

Probably for this code:

```
        if(isset($_SESSION['facebook_access_token'])){
            $facebook_access_token = $_SESSION['facebook_access_token'];
        }else{
            $facebook_access_token = $facebook_helper->getAccessToken();
            $_SESSION['facebook_access_token'] = $facebook_access_token;
            $facebook->setDefaultAccessToken($_SESSION['facebook_access_token']);
        }

        $graph_response = $facebook->get('/me?fields=name,email', $facebook_access_token);
```

Comment: It would probably help to post a full stack trace so that we can see which method above is leading to that warning

Answer (score 0):

```
$facebook = new \Facebook\Facebook([
    'app_id' => 'APP_ID',
    'app_secret' => 'APP_SECRET',
    'default_graph_version' => 'v10.0',
]);
      
define('FB_REDIRECT_URL', $redirect_url);

// Get redirect login helper
$facebook_helper = $facebook->getRedirectLoginHelper();
$_SESSION['FBRLH_state'] = $_GET['state'];

if(($_GET['code'] && $_GET['state'])) {

    if(isset($_SESSION['facebook_access_token'])){
        $facebook_access_token = $_SESSION['facebook_access_token'];
    }else{
        $facebook_access_token = $facebook_helper->getAccessToken();
        $_SESSION['facebook_access_token'] = $facebook_access_token;
        $facebook->setDefaultAccessToken($_SESSION['facebook_access_token']);
    }

    $graph_response = $facebook->get('/me?fields=name,email', $facebook_access_token);

    $facebook_user_info = $graph_response->getGraphUser();

    if(!empty($facebook_user_info['name']))
    {
        $_SESSION['facebook_user_name'] = $facebook_user_info['name'];
    }

    if(!empty($facebook_user_info['email']))
    {
        $_SESSION['facebook_user_email'] = $facebook_user_info['email'];
    }
}
else
{
    $facebook_permissions = ['email'];

    $facebook_login_url = $facebook_helper->getLoginUrl(FB_REDIRECT_URL, $facebook_permissions);
}
```

Comment: Anybody? Any idea?

Comment: This does not appear to be an _answer_ to the question, so please don’t post it as one. _Edit_ your question, to include the code in there.